# Speech recognition script is not working for me

Tags: javascript

```js
var SpeechRecognition = SpeechRecognition || webkitSpeechRecognition
var SpeechGrammarList = SpeechGrammarList || webkitSpeechGrammarList
var SpeechRecognitionEvent = SpeechRecognitionEvent || webkitSpeechRecognitionEvent

var colors = [ 'aqua' , 'azure' , 'beige', 'bisque', 'black', 'blue', 'brown', 'chocolate', 'coral', 'crimson', 'cyan', 'fuchsia', 'ghostwhite', 'gold', 'goldenrod', 'gray', 'green', 'indigo', 'ivory', 'khaki', 'lavender', 'lime', 'linen', 'magenta', 'maroon', 'moccasin', 'navy', 'olive', 'orange', 'orchid', 'peru', 'pink', 'plum', 'purple', 'red', 'salmon', 'sienna', 'silver', 'snow', 'tan', 'teal', 'thistle', 'tomato', 'turquoise', 'violet', 'white', 'yellow'];
var grammar = '#JSGF V1.0; grammar colors; public <color> = ' + colors.join(' | ') + ' ;'

var recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
var speechRecognitionList = new SpeechGrammarList();
speechRecognitionList.addFromString(grammar, 1);
recognition.grammars = speechRecognitionList;
//recognition.continuous = false;
recognition.lang = 'en-US';
recognition.interimResults = false;
recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;

var diagnostic = document.querySelector('.output');
var bg = document.querySelector('html');
var hints = document.querySelector('.hints');

var colorHTML= '';
colors.forEach(function(v, i, a){
  console.log(v, i);
  colorHTML += '<span style="background-color:' + v + ';"> ' + v + ' </span>';
});
hints.innerHTML = 'Tap/click then say a color to change the background color of the app. Try '+ colorHTML + '.';

document.body.onclick = function() {
  recognition.start();
  console.log('Ready to receive a color command.');
}

recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  // The SpeechRecognitionEvent results property returns a SpeechRecognitionResultList object
  // The SpeechRecognitionResultList object contains SpeechRecognitionResult objects.
  // It has a getter so it can be accessed like an array
  // The [last] returns the SpeechRecognitionResult at the last position.
  // Each SpeechRecognitionResult object contains SpeechRecognitionAlternative objects that contain individual results.
  // These also have getters so they can be accessed like arrays.
  // The [0] returns the SpeechRecognitionAlternative at position 0.
  // We then return the transcript property of the SpeechRecognitionAlternative object

  var last = event.results.length - 1;
  var color = event.results[last][0].transcript;

  diagnostic.textContent = 'Result received: ' + color + '.';
  bg.style.backgroundColor = color;
  console.log('Confidence: ' + event.results[0][0].confidence);
}

recognition.onspeechend = function() {
  recognition.stop();
}

recognition.onnomatch = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = "I didn't recognise that color.";
}

recognition.onerror = function(event) {
  diagnostic.textContent = 'Error occurred in recognition: ' + event.error;
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1, p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
}

.hints span {
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <title>Speech color changer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Speech color changer</h1>

    <p class="hints"></p>
    <div>
        <p class="output"><em>...diagnostic messages</em></p>
    </div>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am not able to understand why my script is not working.Actually i am not able to use microphone.It shows not allowed.Please help this is my college project.
i tried to make it allow in settings in my browser but still i am not able to.why am i not allowed to use microphone i tried many google solutions but still i am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome, at least, won't give microphone permission to a page loaded via the `file` scheme. You need to spin up a webserver and access the page that way.